# ENTRYPOINT を一時的に無視して docker コンテナを起動したい

Tags: docker

mlflow という機械学習用の python ライブラリで作られた docker image があるのですが
その中身を編集（具体的には ssh のインストールと鍵を設置）したいです

`mlflow sagemaker build-and-push-container --no-push`
というコマンドでローカルに mlflow-pyfunc というイメージが作成されたのですが

`docker run -it mlflow-pyfunc bash`

と中に入ろうとしても

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mlflow/models/container/__init__.py", line 53, in _init
    args=str(sys.argv)))
Exception: Unrecognized command bash, full args = ['-c', 'bash']
```

という ENTRYPOINT に書かれてあるコマンドが実行されてしまい
コンテナを起動することができません

この ENTRYPOINT のコマンドの詳細はよくわからないのですが
このイメージを sagemaker という AWS のサービスで使うために必要な内容だと思うので残したいです

**ENTRYPOINT を維持したまま**中のイメージを変更する方法はないでしょうか

--

#### 追記

docker run のオプションに --entrypoint でエントリポイントを上書きする方法はあるみたいで

```
docker run -it --name mlflow-pyfunc --entrypoint '' mlflow-pyfunc bash -c "apt-get -y update; apt-get -y install openssh-client; apt-get -y clean"

docker cp ssh_files/. mlflow-pyfunc:.ssh
```

でコンテナ上のファイルの設置はできたのですが

`docker commit mlflow-pyfunc mlflow-pyfunc`

でイメージに反映してしまうと ENTRYPOINT も上書きされてしまい
この後このイメージの本来の使い方ができなくなります

Comment: `--entrypoint` オプションで entry point を空欄にするとコンテナ内に入ることができます。`docker run --entrypoint '' -it mlflow-pyfunc bash`

Comment: オプションがあったのですね。調査不足でした。ありがとうございます

Comment: すみません。やっぱりこの方法だと一時的ではなく entrypoint 自体が上書きされてしまうようです。編集したイメージで sagemaker にデプロイできなかったので調べたところ、１度 --entrypoint で run して保存したイメージは次に --entrypoint なしでもログインできてしまいます。やはり entrypoint を維持したまま編集というのは無理でしょうか

Answer (score 0):

docker runは、「新しくコンテナを作成」するコマンドです。
やりたいことは起動しているコンテナに対してコマンドを実行することでしょうから、docker execを使いましょう。

Answer (score 0):

ENTRYPOINT を使ったことがないので残せるかは不明ですが
Dockerfile に FROM でよみこんで別のイメージを生成するのはだめなんでしょうか

```
FROM mlflow-pyfunc
RUN apt-get -y update; apt-get -y install openssh-client; apt-get -y clean
COPY ssh_files /root/.ssh
```

`docker build -t my-image .`

Comment: やってみたのですがどうもうまくいってないようです。 ENTRYPOINT は残っていたのですが sagemaker デプロイした際初めから１つのDockerfileで作った場合は動くのに、分割して from で読み込んで作成した場合は起動に失敗します。イメージ名に依存してる場所があったりするのかもしれません